# Given $G = \mathbb{Z}_6 \times\mathbb{Z}_6$ with a particular operation, find $Z(G)$ and $G/Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Given the group $G = \mathbb{Z}_6 \times\mathbb{Z}_6$ and the following operation:
$$(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(a+(-1)^bc,b+d)$$
find (or classify) $Z(G)$ and $G/Z(G)$.

For the first part, I found that $(a,b) \in Z(G) \Leftrightarrow(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(c,d) \cdot (a,b) \text{ for every }(c,d) \in G \Leftrightarrow a(1+(-1)^{d+1})=c(1+(-1)^{b+1}) \Rightarrow Z(G)=\langle(0,2)\rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_3$.

I'm having troubles on the second part though; I know that $|G/Z(G)|=12=2^23$, and I also know that there's either a normal $2$-Sylow or a normal $3$-Sylow, but at this point I'm stuck. Some hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$The two subsets $A = \Set{(x, 0) : x \in \Z_{6}}$ and $B = \Set{(0, y) : y \in \Z_{6}}$ are subgroups, and $B$ normalises $A$, as
$$\begin{align}
(0, 1)^{-1} (1, 0) (0, 1)
&=
(0, -1) (1, 0) (0, 1)\\
&=
(-1, -1) (0, 1)\\
&=
(-1, 0).
\end{align}$$
So $G$ is a semidirect product of $A$ by $B$, with $b = (0, 1)$ inducing the inversion automorphism on $A$. It follows that $Z(G) = \Span{(3, 0), (0, 2)}$ has order $6$. A Sylow $3$-subgroup is normal, while Sylow $2$-subgroups are not, as $a = (1, 0)$ conjugates $\Set{(0, 0), (3, 0), (0, 3), (3, 3)}$ to $\Set{(0, 0), (3, 0), (1, 3), (4, 3)}$.

Comment: thanks for your answer! It's not entirely clear to me why "It follows that $Z(G)=\langle (3,0),(0,2) \rangle$", could you please elaborate a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Since $b = (0, 1)$ induces inversion on $A$, $b^{2} = (0, 2)$ must induce the identity. And then $(3, 0)^{-1} = (-3, 0) = (3, 0)$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$An afterthought. It follows from the above that $G$ is a direct product $\Span{(2,0), (0, 3)} \times \Span{(3,0), (0, 2)}$, where the first factor is isomorphic to $S_{3}$, and the second one (the centre) is cyclic of order $6$.